# Smooch bot running over Heroku platform returns error 503 looking for favicon

Tags: heroku, favicon, http-status-code-503, smooch

I have an app ( smooch) running over Heroku. But for a while now I have had it return error 503's at me. I have no idea. It says he is looking for a favicon but in vain. No matter what I do noting is helping.

So firstly: I have used  Heroku Belt on my mac and saw this msg - though the deploy was ok and got a green checkbox - so rather weird:

016-10-10T22:19:29.206225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=independerchat.herokuapp.com request_id=a5c658c2-7ba3-413e-b81d-d80864b8fccf fwd="213.46.87.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Secondly also did a rollback but that did not help either.
And lastly it has been around for a good week now......

Any help would be greately appreciated!

Thanks!

Wouter

Comment: Finding access to `/favicon.ico` in your logs is normal. Many browsers does this by default. If you declared a favicon in your code, it's alright: browsers will look there too and your visitors won't notice the issue. This is a very classic setup, expect for the 503 (404 is usually returned).

Answer (score 0):

@philippe_b is correct. [smooch-bot-example](https://github.com/alavers/smooch-bot-example) an express app, so your best bet to resolve this issue would be to simply serve a favicon. I recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-favicon

`npm install serve-favicon`

and in app.js:

`app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/yourfavicon.ico'));`

**Edit:** If you don't have a favicon you can generate one at RealFaviconGenerator.net ;)